# Why are optional constructor parameters are not considered during dependency resolution

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have a class that implements `ITranslator` as below:

```
public SignalTranslator(
 bool compress = false,
 bool validate = false,
 int maxThreads = 2)
{
  // ctor logic
}
```

I register this implementation as follows:

```
Container.RegisterType(typeof(ITranslator), typeof(SignalTranslator));
```

Since all constructor parameters are optional, shouldn't the service resolution work without any issue?

I'm getting the below error during service resolution:

```
InvalidOperationException: The type Boolean does not have an accessible constructor.
```

For now, I addressed this issue by having a parameterless ctor as below:

```
[InjectionConstructor]
public SignalTranslator()
  : this(false)
{
}
```

But another branch (latest) of the same repo did not have this issue. I suspect if the newer branch is referring to a more recent version of unity package and the issue I'm facing is part of an older package.

Just wanted to know if there is a better way to address this.

Comment: Optional parameters are a **compile-time** thing. However, resolution (at run-time) _might_ consider them but that would be unexpected for many and make things more complicate that they (probably) need to be.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify it as an optional param :

`Container.RegisterType(typeof(ITranslator), typeof(SignalTranslator), new OptionalParameter());`